# I can't get sembast to initialize

Tags: flutter, sembast

i am trying to use sembast in my app in flutter. As soon as I try to get a data it tells me that the DB is not initialized.
This problem only appears if I use a physical device.

This is my sembast class:

```
class Sembast {
  late final dir;
  late final _dbPath;
  late Database _db;
  late StoreRef _store;

  Sembast({required this.dir});

  Future<bool> inizializa({required String fileName}) async {
    
    try {
      await dir.create(recursive: true);
      _dbPath = path.join(dir.path, fileName);
      // open the database
      _db = await databaseFactoryIo.openDatabase(_dbPath);
      _store = StoreRef<String, dynamic>.main();
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  Future add({required String key, required dynamic value}) async {
    await _store.record(key).put(_db, value);
  }

  Future addMap({required String key, required Map<String, dynamic> value}) async {
    await _store.record(key).put(_db, value);
  }

  Future update({required String key, required dynamic value}) async {
    var record = _store.record(key);
    await record.delete(_db);
    await add(key: key, value: value);
  }

  Future delete({required String key}) async {
    var record = _store.record(key);
    await record.delete(_db);
  }

  Future<dynamic> get({required String key}) async {
    var data = await _store.record(key).get(_db);
    return data;
  }
}
```

as soon as I try to get some data I get an error telling me that sembast is not initialized:

```
var d = await sembast.get(key: "DataAggiornamento") as String;
```

this is the value cher appears when debugging:

> _db: not initialized
>
> _dbPath:"/data/user/0/..../app_flutter/my_database.db"
>
> _store: not initialized

this is how i initialize sembast:

```
var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
sembast = Sembast(dir: dir);
await sembast.inizializa(fileName: "my_database.db");
```

any suggestions?

Comment: are you awaiting `inizializa` method once before calling the get method?

Comment: yes: var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      sembast = Sembast(dir: dir);
      await sembast.inizializa(fileName: "my_database.db");

Comment: can you check for the value returned when initialize is called. Is it true or false?

Comment: it always comes back true to me

Comment: You might need storage permission for the same. You can try using getApplicationSupportDirectory

Comment: I tried, but no same result